# t-test for more than 30 samples?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I'm conducting a study that requires to compare the means of dependent groups and independent groups. I thought that t-test would be the best test. But I'm having doubts since I know that t-test is used when the samples are less than 30.

So can I still use t-test even if my I used 150 samples for both groups? Thanks

Comment: The t-test works for any sample size. There's nothing magical about n=30; indeed in my book the t-test isn't much like the z near typical significance levels (5% to 1%) until well past n=30. Eventually the tables become very close to the z-tables a fair way into the tail.

Comment: As implied by @Glen_b's comment, "more than 30 samples" is science talk; "a sample size more than 30" is statistics talk. The difference does not usually cause confusion, and others here adjusted to your terminology, but please note.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the t-distribution becomes closer to the normal distribution as degree of freedom increases. When df approaches 30, it will be practically the same as normal distribution. The figures on [t-distribution Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) clearly shows the process.

So basically "t-test is used when the samples are less than 30", just because there is no need to use is anymore with a higher number. Of course you can still use t-test with more samples.

Answer (score 5):

There is no upper limit on the number of samples for any kind of t-test.

You may be getting confused with the fact that the t-distribution becomes almost identical to the normal distribution when df > 30.

Comment: I'd dispute the "almost identical". Consider a 1% test and a t-statistic of 2.7 with n=31 (on a one sample test -- so 30 df). If you look up the t-table you will not reject (p=1.13%) but if you look up the z-table your p-value isn't even close to the borderline (p< 0.07%). If you are doing something like Bonferroni-adjusted multiple comparisons the differences get more alarming.